# SQL Between Two Dates with Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an SQL statement that I am trying to use to connect a vb.net program to an access database.  I am using to date/time pickers to provide the dates.  I have searched around and the various changes I have made to the statement have not returned any results.  For what its worth this query works ok within access:

```
   SELECT * FROM tblcallLog 
     WHERE startDate Between #" & dspstart.text & "# AND #" & dtpend.text & "#"
```

---

OK here is the entire click event, per @ajax81's request

enter code here

```
Private Sub btnDateUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDateUpdate.Click
        grpT2DateRange.Visible = True
        grpT2SingleStaff.Visible = True
        grpT2Transfer.Visible = True
        lblT2TotalCallsData.Visible = True


        Dim strSDate As String = dtpStart.Text
        Dim strEDate As String = dtpEnd.Text

        'CountDate Variables
        Dim strSQLCountDate As String = _
 "SELECT * FROM tblcallLog WHERE startDate Between #" & dtpStart.Text & "# AND #" &  dtpEnd.Text & "#"
        Dim odaCallDate As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLCountDate, strPath)
        Dim datCallDateCount As New DataTable
        Dim intDateCount As Integer

        intDateCount = datCallDateCount.Rows.Count
        lblT2TotalCallsData.Text = intDateCount.ToString
enter code here
```

Comment: try using a parameterized query, it will probably work better and avoid sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: You showed us what works.  What are you doing that does not work?  A snippet of the code that is not returning any results is necessary to give you any meaningful help.

Answer (score 0):

A small 'gotcha' that pegged me a few months ago was that the dates weren't being input in the same format; ie make sure you're comparing mm/dd/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy and not mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy.

Edit: 
Another small 'gotcha' I just noticed  -- date field id's that are used for between statements tend to be prefixed with the same acronym. Are you sure you're referencing the correct fields? (you've got dspStart and dtpEnd...)

Comment: I'm ok with the fields... that was a typeo on my part.  The interesting this is the 'value' property of the date time picker it is also returning the time as well as the date.  However, I setup a value in 'custom' for 'mm/dd/yyyy'  and I assigned dtpstart.text and dtpend.text to variables and showed them to the screen... they only returned dates.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm...is there any chance that your query is firing before the datetimes get formatted properly?  Perhaps you can post your code as an edit to your question so the community can better see what's happening.

Comment: added additional code per your suggestion.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Figured it out. A dumb mistake.  Forgot to fill the table. :)  Thanks for everyone's suggestions.